# google sheets trouble with xml

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull data from UPS for tracking into a spreadsheet. The signedforbyname part of the XML feed is sometimes there and sometimes not. When it isn't there, I get an issue:
TypeError: Cannot read property "Text" from undefined. (line 60, file "Code")
If I comment out line 60 that is looking for the signedforbyname I am fine after I also pull the variable out of the string that is supposed to be generated.

I'm not very familiar with javascript so I am probably just doing a daft syntax thing, which would be great. I am all for easy answers. If someone could point me in the right direction with this snippit, I would appreciate it.

I figured that an if then to check if the value is there would be the way to go, but that doesn't seem to be working either as the same error occurs in the same place with or without the if/then (even if I messed up the syntax).

Code that I missed the mark on:

```
catch(err) {
if (jsonText.TrackResponse.Shipment.Package.Activity.ActivityLocation.SignedForByName.Text !==null){
  var signedBy = jsonText.TrackResponse.Shipment.Package.Activity.ActivityLocation.SignedForByName.Text;}
  else {var signedBy = "No Signature";}
var dropLocation = jsonText.TrackResponse.Shipment.Package.Activity.ActivityLocation.Description.Text;
var estDate = 'Signed By: '+signedBy+' @ '+dropLocation;
```

XML from log:

```
[15-03-28 07:52:43:381 CST] Xml.parse([<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TrackResponse><Response><ResponseStatusCode>1</ResponseStatusCode><ResponseStatusDescription>Success</ResponseStatusDescription></Response><Shipment><Shipper><ShipperNumber>xxxx</ShipperNumber><Address><AddressLine1>xxxxx</AddressLine1><City>TRACY</City><StateProvinceCode>CA</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>95304   9370</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></Shipper><ShipTo><Address><City>ROUNDUP</City><StateProvinceCode>MT</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>59072</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address></ShipTo><ShipmentWeight><UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement><Weight>4.90</Weight></ShipmentWeight><Service><Code>003</Code><Description>GROUND</Description></Service><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>xxxxxxxx</Value></ReferenceNumber><ShipmentIdentificationNumber>1ZA85Y090310073852</ShipmentIdentificationNumber><PickupDate>20150318</PickupDate><DeliveryDateUnavailable><Type>Scheduled Delivery</Type><Description>Scheduled Delivery Date is not currently available, please try back later</Description></DeliveryDateUnavailable><Package><TrackingNumber>1ZA85Y090310073852</TrackingNumber><Activity><ActivityLocation><Address><City>ROUNDUP</City><StateProvinceCode>MT</StateProvinceCode><PostalCode>59072</PostalCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode></Address><Code>MP</Code><Description>GARAGE</Description></ActivityLocation><Status><StatusType><Code>D</Code><Description>DELIVERED</Description></StatusType><StatusCode><Code>FS</Code></StatusCode></Status><Date>20150323</Date><Time>131200</Time></Activity><PackageWeight><UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement><Weight>4.90</Weight></PackageWeight><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>FN1-2514196-2965923</Value></ReferenceNumber><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>D3M0KFD7K</Value></ReferenceNumber><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>NA</Value></ReferenceNumber><ReferenceNumber><Code>01</Code><Value>UPS-CAOAK-T00441361L  UPS842508  UP</Value></ReferenceNumber></Package></Shipment></TrackResponse>, true]) [0.067 seconds]
[15-03-28 07:52:43:450 CST] Logger.log([{TrackResponse={Response={ResponseStatusCode={Text=1}, ResponseStatusDescription={Text=Success}}, Shipment={ShipmentIdentificationNumber={Text=1ZA85Y090310073852}, Service={Description={Text=GROUND}, code={Text=003}}, ReferenceNumber={Value={Text=129821607}, code={Text=01}}, Shipper={address={PostalCode={Text=95304   9370}, StateProvinceCode={Text=CA}, CountryCode={Text=US}, AddressLine1={Text=xxxxx}, City={Text=TRACY}}, ShipperNumber={Text=xxxx}}, Package={Activity={Status={StatusCode={code={Text=FS}}, StatusType={Description={Text=DELIVERED}, code={Text=D}}}, Time={Text=131200}, Date={Text=20150323}, ActivityLocation={Description={Text=GARAGE}, address={PostalCode={Text=59072}, StateProvinceCode={Text=MT}, CountryCode={Text=US}, City={Text=ROUNDUP}}, code={Text=MP}}}, ReferenceNumber=[{Value={Text=FN1-2514196-2965923}, code={Text=01}}, {Value={Text=D3M0KFD7K}, code={Text=01}}, {Value={Text=NA}, code={Text=01}}, {Value={Text=UPS-CAOAK-T00441361L  UPS842508  UP}, code={Text=01}}], TrackingNumber={Text=1ZA85Y090310073852}, PackageWeight={UnitOfMeasurement={code={Text=LBS}}, Weight={Text=4.90}}}, ShipmentWeight={UnitOfMeasurement={code={Text=LBS}}, Weight={Text=4.90}}, DeliveryDateUnavailable={Description={Text=Scheduled Delivery Date is not currently available, please try back later}, Type={Text=Scheduled Delivery}}, PickupDate={Text=20150318}, ShipTo={address={PostalCode={Text=59072}, StateProvinceCode={Text=MT}, CountryCode={Text=US}, City={Text=ROUNDUP}}}}}}, []]) [0.001 seconds]
[15-03-28 07:52:43:451 CST] Logger.log([1, []]) [0 seconds]
[15-03-28 07:52:43:523 CST] Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "Text" from undefined. (line 60, file "Code") [0.551 seconds total runtime]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: try checking for the condition of just `SignedForByName`:

```
if (jsonText.TrackResponse.Shipment.Package.Activity.ActivityLocation.SignedForByName) { ... }
```

Then set your variable to `...SignedForByName.Text` if `SignedForByName` exists.

Testing out your JSON object, I replicated your error message when looking for `SignedForName.Text` but got `undefined` when trying to access `SignedForByName`.

Comment: I tried editing it to what you suggested and got the same error. Same with !==undefined. Any other ideas what I can do here?

TypeError: Cannot read property "Text" from undefined. (line 60, file "Code")Dismiss

Comment: Hmm, I'll try it out, but are you sure you're getting into the `catch` block? Maybe include more context in the question?

Comment: well line 60 is the line in the catch block and if I strip out the if/then stuff and just comment it out, it goes through and processes just fine... unless there is a signature, in which case it misses it since it is commented out... I am not sure what kind of context you are looking for.

Basically I am trying to deal with the undefined value when it isn't there. The code doesn't like it and generates the error and I can't seem to write code to deal with it. I don't know why it is in the catch at all actually. I don't see anything occurring with the err later.

Comment: nailed it! Thank you!